# It is possible to use class TextToSpeach from android API without price and limitation?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech

It is possible to use android api class TextToSpeach from API without limitation? Or is there are any limitations?

I found google cloud text to speach AI api in google's cloud platform, but is it the same like android api class ?

In the system settings i have google TTS module active. It is connected with google cloud or how it is working on the background ?

I'm not using any API key in my app. Whean i disable internet TTS is still working.

It is safe to use it for commercial use?

Comment: Is your question about google cloud [Text-to-speech](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/)  or  [google text to speech](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/text-to-speech-tts/cpnomhnclohkhnikegipapofcjihldck?pli=1)?

Comment: It is about this API https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech . It should not be cloud version.

Comment: If you want to know more about google cloud text to speech api and its limitations,you can refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech?hl=en) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/quotas).